# How to make variable value available in a second nested while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I currently have a while loop which has another while loop running inside of it, I want to reference a value which is changed by the first loop each time the second loop is run.

```
$counter = 0;
$counter2 = 2;

while ($counter < 7) {
    $name = 0;
    while ($array[$counter2][2] == !false) {
        if ($array[$counter2][3] == "string") {
            if ($array[$counter2][2] == $counter) {
                $name = 1;
            }
        }
        $counter2++;
    }
    $counter++;
}
```

When I run the above and do the second IF statement the value of $counter is 0 even though this should go up through each iteration of the first loop.

How do I get the value of $counter in the second while loop to match the $counter I am using in the first while loop?

Comment: You are increasing `$counter2`, but you are referencing `$array[$counter2]`. These two are obviously not the same

Comment: In the first `while1` iteration, `$counter` will be 0, and will stay 0 through all `while2` iterations. That is normal because that is what you coded here. On the 2d `while1` iteration, `$counter` will be 1, etc. Please be more specific about what you are exactly trying to do.

Comment: It might help to initialize the values for both counters so we know where we're starting.

Comment: The second while loop is supposed to run 7 times in total, each time it is run I want the value of the counter it checks in the second if statement to increase by 1. The second loop in actuality is cycling through some array data I have taken from a csv.

Comment: @caCtus That is what I am trying to do but the value of $counter never goes up even on the 2nd, 3rd etc run of the first while loop, it is always 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I have solved my issue, I was forgetting to reset the value of counter2 at the start of the first loop each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second loop was only ever running once because the array search would always start off as false due to the fact I wasn't resetting the second counter each time the first loop was run.